# Difference between etymologies of 'allocable' and 'allocatable'

Tags: etymology, differences, is-it-a-word, variants

Which one is more proper to use: 'allocable' or 'allocatable'? Sources say the former is derived from the original Latin word 'allocare', while the latter is a part-of-speech-variant of the English word 'allocate'.
Also, is there a standard rule in English to form able-ending adjective of words terminating in 'ate'?

Thank you.

Comment: Ngram clearly shows that "allocable" is the more used term between the two: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=allocable%2Callocatable&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Callocable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Callocatable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ***-able***: 
 - word-forming element expressing ability, capacity, fitness, from French, from Latin -ibilis,.. a suffix used to form nouns of instrument. 
in Latin, infinitives in -are took -abilis, others -ibilis; ***in English, -able tends to be used with native (and other non-Latin) words, -ible with words of obvious Latin origin (but there are exceptions).***  The Latin suffix is not etymologically connected with able, but it long has been popularly associated with it, and this has contributed to its survival as a living suffix. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-able

Answer (score 2):

The first *Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary* to take notice of either *allocable* or *allocatable* is the fourth edition (1931/1934) which has this listing in its new words section (meaning that it was not included in the original (1931) version of the fourth edition):

> **allocable** *a.* capable of being allocated.

The rival word *allocatable* doesn't appear until the eighth edition (1973), which offers these consecutive entries:

> **allocable** *adj* **1 :** capable of being allocated **2 :** assignable in accounting to a particular account or to a particular period of time
>
> **allocate** *vt* **-cated, -cating** {ML *allocatus*, pp. of *allocare*, fr. L *ad-* + *locare* to place, fr. *locus* place — more at STALL} **1 :** to apportion for a specific purpose or to a specific purpose or to particular persons or things : DISTRIBUTE <*allocate* tasks among human and automated components> **2 :** to set apart or earmark : DESIGNATE <*allocate* a section of the building for special research purpoes> — **allocatable** *adj* — **allocation** *n* — **allocator** *n*

It thus appears that either *allocable* or *allocatable* is acceptable when the meaning of the word is "capable of being allocated"—that is, either "distributed" or "designated"—but in the field of accounting, the meaning "assigned to a particular account or period of time" calls for *allocable* and not *allocatable*. This special case favoring *allocable*—which actually debuted, in somewhat more general terms, in the fifth edition (1936)—vanishes in the ninth edition (1983) and doesn't appear in either the tenth edition (1993) or the eleventh edition (2003). So for the past 40 years, MW has not provided any basis for using *allocable* rather than *allocatable* to convey a specialized meaning in accounting.

The *Ninth* through *Eleventh Collegiates* report that the earliest occurrence of *allocable* in MW's files is from 1916; MW doesn't provide a first occurrence date for the form *allocatable*. However, a Google Books search for *allocable* turns up instances of the word from as early as the late eighteenth century. From the entry for "Stipend" in [*The Decisions of the [Scottish] Court of Session from Its First Institution to the Present Time*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9b5NAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA301&dq=%22allocable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFr_Wk5cD5AhVFOH0KHZ1UAFQQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22allocable%22&f=false), volume 4 (1797):

> The parishes of Inverarity and Methil in the shire of Forfar being under different patronages, were united *quoad omnia* above a century ago. A decree of augmentation being obtained, the question occurred, How the augmented stipend was to be localled? The Lords found, That the stipend modified was to be divided equally betwixt the parishes, effeiring to their rentals proven ; and that each patron has right only to allocate his proportion thereof within his own parish. Fotheringham *contra* Bower and others. July 13. 1774.——The Lords found, That where a joint feu-duty [tenure payment] is payable for stock and teind [tithe], the portion paid for the latter is free teind, and **allocable**, *primo loco*, for stipend. Feb. 13. 1793, Sir Thomas Dundas *contra* Baikie.

And from [The Officers of State and the Earl of Breadalbane contra Duncan Campbell of Lochnell](https://books.google.com/books?id=g-sDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA77&dq=%22allocable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFr_Wk5cD5AhVFOH0KHZ1UAFQQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22allocable%22&f=false) (March 7, 1770), reprinted in *Decisions of the Court of Sessions, from 1752 to (1808)*

> The question now agitated was decided in the case of the minister of Arngask in 1715 ; where the court found "That the teinds belonging to heritors, by virtue of heritable rights, were **allocable** to the minister, before the teinds formerly belonging to the bishops and their tacksman, and now belonging to his Majesty."

The word *allocable* also occurs multiple times in J. Slater Lewis, [*The Commercial Organisation of Factories*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CCcoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA220&dq=%22allocable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil8PPo68D5AhWfGDQIHVnaARQ4KBDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22allocable%22&f=false) (1896) and in A. Hamilton Church, "[Stocktaking](https://books.google.com/books?id=yUc8AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA564&dq=%22allocable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ9fS47MD5AhV7IjQIHZFYCRM4PBDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22allocable%22&f=false)" in *Feildan's Magazine* (December 1901).

As for *allocatable*, it begins to appear in print no later than 1890. From E.P. Mulhallen Marum, [*Taxation and the Taxable Bases of the United Kingdom*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hw5FAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22allocatable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT-dHV7cD5AhUgHjQIHR8bB8wQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22allocatable%22&f=false) (1890):

> Taking into account that this rent-charge is subject to a corn average deduction, and that the wheat average (of 1832) at its inception was £1 12s. 10d. per brl., and is now quoted at 16s. per barrel, it may be fairly affirmed that the above rent-charge represents, or its capitalised value, not more than the one-third properly **allocatable** to Poor Law relief.

From "[Testimony of Julius Kruttschnitt](https://books.google.com/books?id=ln7NAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22allocatable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT-dHV7cD5AhUgHjQIHR8bB8wQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22allocatable%22&f=false)" (November 24, 1899) in *Testimony Taken by the Commission to Investigate the Postal Service* (1901):

> Mr. KRUTTSCHNITT. There was a good deal in his [Mr. Acker's] testimony about the segregation of passenger and freight expenses—a good deal said about expenses on the Lehigh Valley road. I am one of those who long ago ceased trying to do that. Just to show you how little that amounts to, I read the Atchison testimony of Mr. Kenna very carefully. In that a study was made, or the results of a study were given, as to the difference in cost of operating passenger and freight trains. A certain number of the expenses were divided, and a certain number of the expenses were not **allocatable** and were divided on the train mileage basis arbitrarily ; and Mr. Kenna reached this result, that the passenger service of the the Atchison cost nine and a half millions and the freight service twenty millions, the two together maing up the total of thirty millions.

And from J.W. Root, [*Studies in British National Finance*](https://books.google.com/books?id=54soAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22allocatable%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT-dHV7cD5AhUgHjQIHR8bB8wQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22allocatable%22&f=false) (1901):

> The estate duties do not afford quite so safe a basis for argument. They are apt to vary from year to year, not only in total yield, but in distribution, though as far as the former is concerned they have hitherto regularly increased. For 1898-9 the total sum was £15,732,000, and again eliminating £206,000 as **allocatable** only to Imperial sources, the separate and average distribution was as follows:— [tabulations omitted].

So whereas *allocable* appears earliest in print as a term in Scottish law of the 1700s and 1800s, *allocatable* appears in quick succession near the turn og the twentieth century, in Ireland, the US, and England. As far as I can see the meaning in the passages I've quoted seems fairly consistent regardless of which form of the word was used.

Here is an Ngram chart of *allocable* (blue line) vs. *allocatable* (red line) for the period 1780–2019:

[image]

As you can see, *allocable* seems to have been considerably more common that *allocatable* in print publications during much of the twentieth century, but that the frequency of the two terms has gotten much closer over the past couple of decades. I see little reason to prefer one over the other at this point.

With regard to the early preference for *allocable* in Scottish law, I wonder whether the spelling was influenced by the standard spelling of *revocable* (another legal term). Although *allocable* comes from Latin *allocare* (to place) and revocable comes from Latin *revocare* (to call), the English verbs associated with the two terms—*allocate* and *revoke*—are hardly a close match, notwithstanding the similarity of the noun forms *allocation* and *revocation*.

In any event, frequency of usage of the forms *allocable* and *allocatable* is at this point so similar that I would feel safe using either one (assuming that the house style of the publisher I was writing for didn't specify a preference of its own).

Answer (score 0):

Computer scientists usually use "allocatable" instead of "allocable" when they wish to say something in a program is capable of being allocated.

For example
"Modern Fortran Explained" by Michael Metcalf, John Reid and Malcolm Cohen (Oxford University Press, 2018) p.25 says

> an array may be given the allocatable attribute ... Its rank is specified when it is declared, but the bounds are undefined until an allocate statement ... has been executed for it.